# How do I stop Safari on my iPad from reloading tabs once they are already open?

Tags: ipad, safari, tabs

For instance, I like reading Quora. They regularly send me digests to my email. What I do is I click the link from the email that opens the digest in Safari tab. I usually prefer to leave those open tabs until later on (usually Sunday) when I go through many tabs at once and read through them all.

Well, this works really well on Chrome browser on my Windows desktop but on my iPad, when I open Safari (say after a week or so) it reloads the page instead of showing what was opened there originally (a week ago.) This results in the old digest being completely reloaded with some new stuff.

Is there any way to make Safari on my iPad stop reloading pages and just keep what was shown there originally? It is very annoying!

Comment: Did you consider adding to your reading list? This way it will even be available for offline reading, and you will be able to scroll to the next page after finishing one instead of switching tabs.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.  You need to think of the nature of the iPad.

It is RAM constrained (and battery constrained, but that probably doesn't affect this as much as RAM), so it often suspends apps so they can be "reconstituted".

Depending on what you do in the week (a long time in app land) the pages would be suspended and removed from memory.  Reopen the browser (and this would be any browser on the iPad, not just Safari) it has to get the pages again to show.

So.. this is what iPads (and to some extent android devices) do.  It remembers where you were and re-gets the page.  Now you could do a Reading List, or even use Pocket (I think Pocket takes a snapshot in time, so may work better).  Those may bring you closer to where you want to be.  But the tabs will be reloaded, because they were gone way before you re-opened safari

Comment: Yep. Right now, the answer is "Buy an iPad with more RAM." Right now, the only option is the iPad Air 2 with 2GB of RAM. If you're already on one of those, you're just stuck.  There are rumors of an iPad Pro coming out but those are only rumors.....

Comment: I do have the latest iPad. The one where they took the bezel out. But it still does it.

Comment: Also concerning RAM and what you explained about reloading. It all makes sense. But doesn't it have some sort of a "page file" where instead of just "dumping" my tabs, it can offload them to the solid state drive or whatever persistent storage it comes with, and then take them from disk when I bring them up. I have 64 GB of that. I'm sure it will have enough storage for my tabs, won't it?

Comment: @AlanShutko I don't think amount of RAM would help too much. A browser using memory for a week is a waste as far as the OS is concerned. You'd suspend even with 16Gb

Answer (score 0):

I guess these links are generic ones, for example a generic link to a start page or a category or such. Clicking on a article headline usually takes you to a dedicated link address, wich may persistently point to that particular article.